# HP zbook 15 G3 does not support Ubuntu 14.04 but it supports Ubuntu 16.04 in UEFI Mode

Tags: dual-boot

I need to install Ubuntu 14.04 in legacy mode for the workstation HP z book 15 G3.
Is it possible to copy driver from Ubuntu 116.04 to Ubuntu 14.04 and install in G3 with legacy mode?
Also its a Dual boot with windows 7.

Comment: You know that 16.04 LTS works. Why do you need 14.04 LTS?

Comment: because 16.04 installs in UEFI mode so Symantec Encrytion that we are doing does not support UEFI and corrupts the disk.

Comment: It is possible to install 16.04.1 LTS in both UEFI and BIOS mode. It will be installed in the same mode as you boot the computer. Some computers select boot mode automatically unless you change a setting in a BIOS/UEFI menu. In most computers it is possible to control boot mode manually. I have (older) HP laptops, where it is possible, but I don't know about your model. If that does not work with the 64-bit version, you can install the 32-bit version, *i386* in the iso file's name. The automatic selection should select BIOS mode for the 32-bit version of Ubuntu.

Comment: when i disable UEFI mode then there is no option showing in boot menu for the USB, it only shows when UEFI is enabled.

Comment: I see. Will this be different with 14.04 LTS? I would think the operating system would make no difference. By the way, would it be possible to find the USB drive (when inserted during boot) among the hard disk drives according to the following link? https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick#Booting_the_Computer_from_USB

Answer (score 0):

I also need Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on my zbook. Could not install it with desktop live CD. Then I succeed using the server image!

BIOS in legacy, graphic in Discrete mode.
Install Ubuntu server 14.04.5 LTS AMD64.
Once booted:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
sudo service lightdm start
```

Then I install nvidia driver.

Works for me.